# Why does this SQL SELECT not run when it uses valid data?

Tags: c#, sql

I'm *practising* with C# and SQL and I'm trying to make a simple `email` + `password` *login* that checks the database to match the input.

Why does this code return the expected `0` when the input is wrong, but says the input string is wrong when correct data is used?

```
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand cmd = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand();
cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text;

cmd.CommandText = 
  "SELECT UserPassword, UserMail FROM Users WHERE UserPassword = '" + 
   textBox2.Text + 
  "' AND UserMail = '" + 
    textBox1.Text + '\''; 

cmd.Connection = sqlConnection1;

sqlConnection1.Open();
int correct = 0;
correct = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar());
sqlConnection1.Close();

if(correct <= 0)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Wrong input. Correct = " + 
                     Convert.ToString(correct) + 
                    "\n" + 
                     cmd.CommandText);
}
```

`textbox1` and `textbox2` are email and password inputs, respectively.

I expected the output of "email5" + "email5" to be 5, since it was the fifth row (same with other valid data), but I got the following **exception**:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.FormatException' occurred in
>   mscorlib.dll
>
> Additional information: Input string was not in a correct format.

Comment: Use parameters!  Don't munge query strings with user input.  And -- even more important -- don't pass unencrypted passwords around.  These should be encrypted on the application side.

Comment: *Hashed, not encrypted.

Comment: You'll get a beautiful SQL injection with this.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7505808/why-do-we-always-prefer-using-parameters-in-sql-statements

Comment: That has never been the correct way to construct SQL  in NET.  And it is wrong to store passwords as plaintext.  Dump whatever tutorial source you are using and find another

Comment: You have more than one problem. 1- SQL Injection, the query should use parameters to avoid improper behavior and security bugs. 2- ExecuteScalar will give you an error if you try de retrieve two fields. 3- Are you trying to convert to an integer the password? Your passwords only can contain numbers? Does not seem right.

Comment: what are trying to achive with   `'" + textBox1.Text + '\'';`    ?

Comment: Beware of injection....!, then you are selecting two columns using `SELECT UserPassword, UserMail`  and you are expecting the output of "email5" + "email5" to be 5. what is the logic then?

Comment: c# will not convert "email5" to 5 cos you say make it an int.

Comment: btw https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executescalar?view=netframework-4.7.2 states that the return of ExecuteScalar is just the first columnof the first row so in this case would only return the password

Comment: I may have been unclear in the post, I will edit it a bit. Thanks for the suggestions in regards to the password, but I am only just starting with SQL and trying to solve basic problems, security isn't my priority now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I can see you want to check if there's *at least one record* in `Users` table with given `UserPassword` and `UserMail` fields' values;
if it is, the *password* and *email* user has provided via `textBox2.Text` and `textBox1.Text` are `correct`. If it's your case

```
    bool correct = false;

    //TODO: better create a connection here and not resuse existing one
    sqlConnection1.Open();

    try { 
      //DONE: wrap IDisposable into using in order to release unmanaged resources
      using (var cmd = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand()) {
        cmd.Connection = sqlConnection1; 

        //DONE: Keep sql be readable
        //DONE: Make sql be parametrized 
        //TODO: Do not store password as a plain text, but its hash
        cmd.CommandText = 
          @"SELECT 1      -- 1 we don't want to return password/eMail back
              FROM Users 
             WHERE UserPassword = @prm_Password 
               AND Upper(UserMail) = Upper(@prm_Email)"; // me@mymail.com == Me@MyMail.com

        // Simplest; more accurate choice .Add("@prm_Password", textBox2.Text, RDBMSType)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@prm_Password", textBox2.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@prm_Email", textBox1.Text);

        using (var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader()) {
          // correct if we can read at least one record
          correct = reader.Read();
        }         
      }
    }
    finally {
      sqlConnection1.Close();
    }

    if (!correct) {
      MessageBox.Show("Wrong input... "); 
    }
```

Comment: Depending on the database collation the call to the `Upper` would not be necesary

Comment: according to his original query, he wants to return email and password, if think it fair to guess otherwise

Comment: @styx: I doubt if we should return `eMail` and `password` back since they are `textBox2.Text` and `textBox1.Text`

Comment: When I try to run this, I get the following error: Connection property has not been initialized.

Comment: @Zane Fray: I'm sorry for the typo; I've skipped `cmd.Connection = sqlConnection1; ` line

Comment: Sorry and feel free to point out if it's frowned upon to say that, I'm new to the site, but that worked! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The error you are getting

> "An unhandled exception of type 'System.FormatException' occurred in
>    mscorlib.dll
>
> Additional information: Input string was not in a correct format."

Is because you are selecting an string value

```
cmd.CommandText = "SELECT **UserPassword**, UserMail FROM Users WHERE ....
```

And then you are trying to convert it to Int

```
correct = Convert.**ToInt32**(cmd.ExecuteScalar());
```

`ExecuteScalar` Executes the query, and returns the first column of the first row in the result set returned by the query. Additional columns or rows are ignored.

So, you are trying to convert the password value to Int32, that's throwing you the error...

If you use

```
cmd.CommandText = "SELECT Count(*) FROM Users WHERE ....
```

The rest of your code will work as that condition is just checking that correct is greater than 0

```
sqlConnection1.Open();
int correct = 0;
correct = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar());
sqlConnection1.Close();

if(correct <= 0)
```

However you must be aware of the risk of SQL Injection and other bad practices, but is out of topic

Comment: I don't think this will answers the question, do you?

Comment: A ExecuteScalar can not retrieve two values!

Comment: how this answer is relevant?

Comment: @ZaneFray Ignore this answer, it is wrong in different ways

Comment: It does indeed remove the error! How can I use the return value of cmd.ExecuteScalar(), though?

Comment: I am trying to explain why his code is wrong, my only suggestion is "change your select or change the type"

Comment: @ZaneFray: what value are you expecting back from ExecuteScalar?

Comment: The first row with the selected data, but it's just the fastest way I've thought of to check if the data is there at all.

Comment: If you want the first row - then ExecuteScalar is the wrong method - this is used to return a single value - in your case it would be the first matching password (where UserMail is also a match) or null if no match. If you want the full row, then [ExecuteReader](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executereader?view=netframework-4.7.2) may be what you should be using.

Comment: How can I use the return value of ExecuteReader?

Comment: See Dmitry's answer - you assign the result to an instance of SqlReader, try to read the record - if successful the fields can be accessed similar to an array - see here : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader?view=netframework-4.7.2

Comment: @bradbury9 I never said that, both fragments of code of my original post was copied directly from the answer and I was trying to explain why they were wrong

Comment: Perhaps when you posted you should have answered the question. Your latest edit does address the problem tho.

Comment: @sujithkarivelil does it now??